# C# Inserting into MySQL putting 0's in place of specified data?

Tags: c#, mysql

This makes little sense to me and I have never seen this, although maybe I am just been naive. I have spent over a little over 2.5 hours trying to find the solution for this but have turned up nothing.

I am using Visual Studio with a win form and the MySQL plugin to insert data into a database and when I go to the database (after code has ran) I find the fields are all 0's.

I was originally filling in the query with real user input data, for debugging I outputted to the log what the query was shortly before running it, and it turned out exactly as expected.

I am now trying to specify raw test data in the query and it still turns around the same result. I have not said to put any 0's in the fields whatsoever.

The code in question is below. I have censored some of the connection information for obvious reasons but the connection is working on my end.

```
String connectionStringThreaded = "server=**censored**;uid=**censored**;pwd=**censored**;database=**censored**;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionStringThreaded;
        connection.Open();
        //Loading data into list box.
        //Loading the existing users into edit list box
        MySqlCommand loadCommand = new MySqlCommand();
        loadCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
        loadCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES (Username = 'Test', FirstName = 'Test', Surname = 'Test', Mobile = '123456789', Password = 'Test', SMSID = '1234', Status = 'DIS')"; //Query text
        loadCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

No exceptions are being thrown when this code runs, but I have no idea what is happening. I have attached an image of the result this code outputs in the mySQL database.

**Image of Result:**

[image: Image of issue encountered in MySQL database]

Comment: Please post the table schema (the `CREATE TABLE` statement).

Comment: Done that long ago, it was created before this script.
I think I know the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL `INSERT` syntax is incorrect. MySQL offers 3 versions ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html )

```
INSERT INTO table ( col1, col2, col3 )
VALUES            (  'x',  123, NULL )
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO table SET col1 = 'x', col2 = 123, col3 = NULL
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO table ( col1, col2, col3 )
SELECT 'x', 123, NULL
```

It looks like you're using the second syntax, but are missing the required `SET` keyword.

Comment: And btw, the `set` syntax is not part of the ansi standard, but the other two options are... probably better to stick with a standard syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You did not execute the command and specify the CommandType  like this:

```
loadCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
....
loadCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

According to Microsoft this might be better when instantiating the command:

```
MySqlCommand loadCommand = new MySqlCommand(
        queryString, connection); //queryString is your SQL
```